# Html.DisplayFor and properties' methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a model, which contains a `DateTime` field `TimeRecorded`. I have also defined an extension method for `DateTime`, which compares it to `DateTime.Now` and describes approximately "how long ago" it was in informal English (not unlike the timestamps on the StackOverflow homepage).

In my view, I attempted the following:

```
@String.Format("{0} - {1}", Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Value),
    Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TimeRecorded.ToRelativeString()))
```

I am greeted with an `InvalidOperationException`, informing me that I can only use `DisplayFor` with "field access, property access, single-dimension array index or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

Now, I know I could easily create a display template for this; however, I would rather avoid the bloat of having a whole separate file just for the sake of formatting a single value. Is there a 'conventional' way of doing this within my current view?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
@String.Format("{0} - {1}", Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Value), Model.TimeRecorded.ToRelativeString())
```

In fact... I don't know what `Model.Value` is, but could you simply do:

```
@string.Format("{0} - {1}", Model.Value, Model.TimeRecorded.ToRelativeString())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create proxy property:

```
RelativeStringTimeRecord
{
    get{return TimeRecorded.ToRelativeString()}
}
```

and use `Html.DisplayFor(m => m.RelativeStringTimeRecord())`